# WooCommerce Deposits plugin does not allow decimal in payment schedule amount

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, decimal, payment

When creating a payment plan, WooCommerce Deposits plugin allows input of decimal numbers, such as 33.33%, for the payment amount. However, when saving the payment plan, the decimal gets stripped off, only leaving the whole numbers (33% in this example). If creating a payment plan of 3 equal payments, the total results to only 99%, losing 1% of the price of the product.

How do I allow decimal in the payment schedule amount?

Comment: What is the question or questions?

Comment: This seems like a good question/comment for the plugin authors. Have you tried contacting WooCommerce support?

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the codes, here's what I found:

On line 133 of class-wc-deposits-plans-admin.php, the plan amount is run through 'absint'.

```
$plan_amounts = array_map( 'absint', $_POST['plan_amount'] );
```

This function makes sure that that number entered becomes a positive number, or integer, but also removes any decimals. I fixed the issue by removing the 'absint' function and replace it with a more useful one, which is 'wc_format_decimal', a woocommerce function for formatting decimals.

```
$plan_amounts = array_map( 'wc_format_decimal', $_POST['plan_amount'] );
```

I hope this helps others.